# Converting a parsed text to integer with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am currently parsing a XML file and one field is an integer that determine the size of the object:

```
 $(xml).find('Boxes').each(function(){
  var top = $box.find('top').text();
  }
```

then to display it with HTML:

```
  var html = '<div class="box" style= top:'+ top +'px; </div>';
```

I want to add a constant number, 300, to `top`, I tried:

```
var html = '<div class="box" style="text-align:left; top:'+(parseInt(top)+300).text()+'px; </div>';
```

But this did not display correctly, is this the right way to do this?

Comment: FWIW, your opening tag isn't closed (missing the last `>`), that might be your problem right there.

Comment: When you define `var topY`, it is within the scope of that function. That variable can't be used outside of the function, so either a) make it global or b) put the html inside the function too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML you're using is invalid. You're not closing your opening tag's `<` with a `>`, and you're not ending your attribute's quotes. To fix this, you'll need to do:

```
var html = '<div class="box" style= top:'+ top +'px;"> </div>';
```

or to add a constant number, just do the following (without the `.text()`, and with the `">`):

```
var html = '<div class="box" style="text-align:left; top:'+(parseInt(top)+300)+'px;"> </div>';
```

Comment: Ah ok, actually I did close it in my code, but I forgot to type in when I asked the question. Thanks for the lookout. And yes the parseInt() worked. Ty!

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong here:

```
(parseInt(top)+300).text()
```

`parseInt(top)+300)` return the Number. Where is no `text` method for Number in Javascript. And you didn't close the tag.
Try this:

```
var html = '<div class="box" style="text-align:left; top:'+(parseInt(top)+300)+'px;"> </div>';
```

Comment: You're not addressing the main problem with his unclosed opening tags and attributes though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by converting the string to number adding a `+` as prefix ( *unary-add* ).

```
+top + 300
```

Should look like:

```
var html = '<div class="box" style="top:'+( +top + 300 )+'px;"></div>';
```

Example:

```
var top = "70";      // String
alert( +top + 300 ); // 370
```