# Incrementing with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each

I am parsing my XML file as the following:

```
$(xml).find('Boxes').each(function(){
    var top = $box.find('top').text();
}
```

then to display it with HTML:

```
var html = '<div class="box" style= top:'+ top +'px; </div>';
```

I need to display each of the box 200 pixels lower than the previous box. Say my XML file has 3 boxes, but how do I add 200px to each box as they are being displayed. Currently they all overlap on top of each other because `top` is 1 for all 3.

```
<Boxes>
    <box>
        <top> 1 </top>
    </box>
    <box>
        <top> 1 </top>
    </box>    
    <box>
        <top> 1 </top>
    </box>  
</Boxes>
```

I tried:

```
var topIncrement;
$(xml).find('Boxes').each(function() {
    var top = $box.find('top').text();
    var html = '<div class="box" style= top: ' + (parseInt(top) + topIncrement) + 'px; </div>';
    topIncrement= topIncrement + 200;
}
```

I thought .each(function()) would act like a loop and each time it finds the next Boxes, it increments top by 200. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var html = ""; // The String containing all the HTML later in the loop

$(xml).find('Boxes').each(function( index ){
  var top = $box.find('top').text();
  html += '<div class="box" style="top:'+ (+top + index*200) +'px;"></div>';
});

$("#yourElement").append( html ); // append only once outside the each! // Faster!
```

**IMPORTANT P.S:**
your prepared `var html` **is invalid!**
(It was also noted by other users on your [**previous question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21393818/converting-a-parsed-text-to-integer-with-jquery)... you did no progress on that matter)
 Use my example for reference.

---

**Also some notes about** `(+top + index*200)`
`+top` will convert your xml string to Number using the *unary-add*
You can also do it like: `var top = +$box.find('top').text();` (see the unary?)

The `.each( index , element )` method allows you to use it's *index argument* (0,1,2...) and just multiply it by `200` to displace your elements

READ the docs! (Always) http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 1):

.find('Boxes').each would loop through all items matching the query "Boxes" which is one.

To loop through each box inside of Boxes you would want to do like $('Boxes box').each(..)

Comment: so, $(xml).find('Boxes box').each(function()..?

Comment: Yes. That would query the "box" elements. It would return an array of the "box" objects.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your $box is defined before use. I'd rather find from 'box' tag. Moreover, watch out weird value of 'top', such as Nan, null or undefined.

```
var topIncrement = 0;
// Parse the 'box' elements from xml file
$(xml).find('box').each(function (idx) {
    var val = $(this).find('top').text()*1;
    if (!val) val = 0;
    var html = '<div class="box" style="top:'+ (val+topIncrement) +'px;">' + ('I am box' + idx) + '</div>';
    $("#boxCantainer").append(html);
    topIncrement += 200;
});
```